# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

am getting an IllegalStateException on some of the newer Android models when i invoke the Mediaplayer. Its mostly Android 6. and 7 phones. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this, and the other "Questions" here dosn't seems to apply to my problem.

Am getting this stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
   at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(MediaPlayer.java)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1369)
   at  org.my.app.IntroVideoSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(IntroVideoSurfaceView.java:51)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:712)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:316)
   at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:10434)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1330)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1330)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1330)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1330)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1438)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7398)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is my class:

```
public class IntroVideoSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private MediaPlayer mp;
private boolean has_started = false;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) public IntroVideoSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init();
}

public IntroVideoSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

public IntroVideoSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public IntroVideoSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
}

@Override public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.onboarding);
    try {
        if (!has_started) {
            has_started = true;
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getDeclaredLength());
        }


      mp.prepare();


        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = getHeight();
        lp.width = getWidth();

        setLayoutParams(lp);
        mp.setDisplay(getHolder());
        mp.setLooping(true);
        mp.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    mp.stop();
  }
}
```

This is my xml file i call in the activity to show the video:

```
      <org.my.app.IntroVideoSurfaceView
       android:id="@+id/surface"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Which line is in number 51?

Comment: Line numer 51 is:   mp.prepare();

Comment: Are you sure that when you reaching the mp.prepare() the mp in status "Initialized"

Comment: Can post you actual implementation of this utility class?

Comment: @datasmurfen,Please quick check on my answer for this thread.[Media Controller in Fragment.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43316833/2122328).

Comment: are you giving marshmallow permission for SDcard read and write or else in manifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the try loop, you `start()` the media player (`Started` state). If you call `prepare()` later on then an `IllegalStateException` would get thrown, because you can only call `prepare()` from an `Initialized` state (the `Stopped` state that you put the media player in with `surfaceDestroyed()` is *not* a valid state to call `prepare()` from). See the [state diagram here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram), and note that according to [the surface life-cycle](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sv-glsv), `surfaceCreated()` may be called multiple times. Therefore, you should put `mp.prepare()` inside the `if` block at the very least.