# How to add mediaController in FragmentDialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I had `setMediaController` but it not show in dialogFragment.

```
class VideoPickerFragment(val bean : Bean) : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.picker_video, container, false)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val videoView = view?.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.vvVerify)
        videoView?.setMediaController(MediaController(this.context))
        videoView?.setVideoPath("${BaseUrlHelper.instance.httpUrl}${bean.Lxdz}")
        videoView?.start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a solution to your problem

```
class VideoPickerFragment(val bean : Bean) : DialogFragment() {
        override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
            return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
        
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picker_video, container, false)
            val videoView = view?.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.vvVerify)
            videoView?.setMediaController(MediaController(getActivity()))
            videoView?.setVideoPath("${BaseUrlHelper.instance.httpUrl}${bean.Lxdz}")
            videoView?.start()
    
            return view
            
            
        }
    
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I try it .But It is Not work. The mediaController was not visiable.

Comment: I found answer   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297919/media-controller-in-fragments

Comment: can not resolved. Thanks. I think the most problem is not `MediaController(activity)`